# null pointer exception at service in spring boot using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a service that has a function that prints a string :

```
@Service
public class Aservice {

    public void write(String test) {
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to call this function in the main function, but it gives me a null pointer exception for the service, what am i doing wrong ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Aservice aservice;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApplication test = new TestApplication();
        test.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        aservice.write("ddd");
    }

}
```

here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.TestApplication.start(TestApplication.java:19)
    at com.example.test.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:15)
```

and here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to run a Spring Boot application is to use the `SpringApplication` run method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
}
```

This will bootstrap the Spring framework, including component scanning, dependency injection, etc.